# identifier not found, trying to show array values in c++

Tags: c++

the following code gives me the error:

```
1>------ Build started: Project: project ding, Configuration: Debug Win32 ------
1>  project ding.cpp
1>project ding.cpp(23): error C3861: 'print': identifier not found
========== Build: 0 succeeded, 1 failed, 0 up-to-date, 0 skipped ==========
```

the code is:

```
#include "stdafx.h"
#include <iostream>
using namespace std;

int main()
{
    int getal = 0;
    const int aantal = 5;
    void print (int a[], int& aantal);
    void invoer(int& getal);

    for(int i=0; i<aantal; i++) 
    invoer( getal);

    cout << "klaar!" << endl;
    cin.get();
}
void invoer( int& getal){
    cout << "voer een getal in:";
    cin >> getal;
    print ();
}
void print ( int a[], int& aantal) {
    for (int i = 0; i < aantal; i++ ){
    cout << a[i] << endl;
    }
}
```

I am trying to show the values in the arrays. im wondering what causes the error and how i can fix it.

edit: ive updated the code and now it looks like this:

```
#include "stdafx.h"
#include <iostream>
using namespace std;
void print (int a[], int& aantal);
void invoer(int& getal);

int main()
{
    int getal = 0;
    const int aantal = 5;

    for(int i=0; i<aantal; i++) 
    invoer( getal);

    cout << "klaar!" << endl;
    cin.get();
}
void invoer( int& getal){
    cout << "voer een getal in:";
    cin >> getal;
    print (int a[], int& aantal);
}
void print (int a[], int& aantal) {
    for (int i = 0; i < aantal; i++ ){
    cout << a[i] << endl;
    }
}
```

it now gives these errors:

```
1>------ Build started: Project: project ding, Configuration: Debug Win32 ------
1>  project ding.cpp
1>project ding.cpp(23): error C2144: syntax error : 'int' should be preceded by ')'
1>project ding.cpp(23): error C2660: 'print' : function does not take 0 arguments
1>project ding.cpp(23): error C2059: syntax error : ')'
========== Build: 0 succeeded, 1 failed, 0 up-to-date, 0 skipped ==========
```

Comment: You declare `void print (int a[], int& aantal)`, but call `print ()`. That won't work. Also, *please* move your forward declarations *before* main, not *in* main.

Comment: thanks for the help! one more thing, now that ive implemented the changes i get the following errors: 1>------ Build started: Project: project ding, Configuration: Debug Win32 ------
1>  project ding.cpp
1>project ding.cpp(23): error C2144: syntax error : 'int' should be preceded by ')'
1>project ding.cpp(23): error C2660: 'print' : function does not take 0 arguments
1>project ding.cpp(23): error C2059: syntax error : ')'
========== Build: 0 succeeded, 1 failed, 0 up-to-date, 0 skipped ==========

Comment: Yes... exactly what I said in my comment 14 minutes ago. You declare `print` with parameters but do not call it with the required parameters. Change the function declaration and body or change the function call.

Comment: Don't put types on the parameters in a function call. You're also, incidentally, missing a definition of the array you're planning to print.

Comment: `print (int a[], int& aantal);` <- this is not a correct function call! And I don't even see any arrays in your program!

Answer (score 2):

In your case the the declaration of `print` is restricted to `main` only. So make the other functions global.

Answer (score 0):

Move these function declarations

```
void print (int a[], int& aantal);
void invoer(int& getal);
```

before main

The problem is that you placed the declaration of function print in main

```
int main()
{
    // ...
    void print (int a[], int& aantal);
    void invoer(int& getal);
    // ...
}
```

In this case this name is visible only inside the body of main. However you use this name also in the body of function invoer where it is not declared. Placing the declaration before main makes the name global and visible in other functions.

Answer (score 0):

Try to implement print and invoer functions above the main function.

Answer (score 0):

You need to do this

```
#include "stdafx.h"`
#include <iostream>
using namespace std;



void print ( int a[], int& aantal) {
    for (int i = 0; i < aantal; i++ ){
    cout << a[i] << endl;
    }
}

void invoer( int& getal){
    cout << "voer een getal in:";
    cin >> getal;
    print ();
}

int main()
{
    int getal = 0;
    const int aantal = 5;
    void print (int a[], int& aantal);
    void invoer(int& getal);

    for(int i=0; i<aantal; i++) 
    invoer( getal);

    cout << "klaar!" << endl;
    cin.get();
}
```

If your main loop runs before it knows how to do the functions you've declared, it'll crash

Comment: And won't compile, because you can't call `print` without parameters.